# Add only 2 ip addresses in httpd.conf file with Listen property

Tags: apache, lampp

I am adding ip like this :

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
```

when restarting apache it giving me error.

```
XAMPP: Error 1! Couldn't start Apache!
XAMPP: Starting diagnose...
XAMPP: Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP: Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/
```

How to make localhost available to only 2 computers in lan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `Listen` actually tells Apache on which ports and ip-addresses it should be hosting the server and not which ip-addresses can access the server. What you are looking for is an [Apache Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) and here you will see that you need to enable the `mod_authz_host` and then you can `Allow` or `Deny` hosts and ip-addresses.

In your httpd.conf look for the following line:

```
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

Make sure there is no '#' in front of the `LoadModule`

Now go down to your configured `VirtualHost` and add the following lines:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #below add your acceptable IPs
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/12.12.12.12 
</Directory>
```

Note that using a hostname will incur a reverse DNS lookup so can be slow.

Comment: @user2198849 Added some edits that will hopefully guide you to success